# How to filter objects by values of foreign objects in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

There are tables `Product` and `Transaction`. In `Product` admin there is a field that shows how many transactions have been created with this product.

Now, I want to filter the period of time in which these transactions were created. For example, there was 30 transactions in the last week, but 100 in the last month.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def num_of_trans(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(created="""DATE_VALUE_HERE""").filter(product=self.id).count()
```

I tried to adjust the `queryset` in a class that extends `SimpleListFilter`, however I did not manage to make it work.

Another thing I thought of was to add an additional parameter to `num_of_trans` function, but it seems there is not way to pass this parameter while using the filter.

I would appreciate any tips.

**EDIT**

```
class MyListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('period')
    parameter_name = 'period'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('7', _('last week')),
            ('30', _('last month')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        period = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=self.value()))
        return queryset.filter(transactions__gte=period)
        # of course it won't work, but represents the idea
```

Comment: Update your question with your SimpleListFilter extended class.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but changing the num_of_trans to a property might allow you to use it in the list_filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Transaction(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='products')

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def num_of_trans_last_week(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        self.products.filter(created__range=(now-timedelta(days=7), now)).count()
```

Comment: Well, it's one way of doing it, however I would prefer using `list_filter`. In your solution I am forced to create a new function for every period. Moreover, all these functions would have to be called every time, what is not so good for performance.

Comment: you don't have to create more functions, you can set a parameter: `def num_of_trans(self, period): .... now-timedelta(days=period)`. Are you sure this doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but I cannot invoke this function with a parameter. It is called automatically by the admin and all I can provide is a name, no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Though I try not to use pure SQL with ORM, using "extra" is the only way I can imagine in this case. Makes 2 extra queries.

```
class MyListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('period')
    parameter_name = 'period'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('7', _('last week')),
            ('30', _('last month')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():  # Count transactions by date
            period = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=int(self.value())
            transaction_ids = Transaction.objects\
                    .filter(created__gte=period)\
                    .values_list('id', flat=True)

            qs = queryset.extra(select={
                    "num_transactions": """
                      SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM appname_transaction 
                      WHERE appname_transaction.id IN ({}) 
                      AND appname_transaction.product_id = appname_product.id
                      """.format(", ".join([str(t_id) for t_id in transaction_ids]))
            })

        else:  # Count all
            qs = queryset.extra(select={
                    "num_transactions": """
                      SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM appname_transaction 
                      WHERE appname_transaction.product_id = appname_product.id
                      """
            })
        return qs


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [MyListFilter, ]
    list_display = [..., 'num_transactions']
    ...

    def num_transactions(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, 'num_transactions')
```